# Symfony 4 + ReactJS Not Working Without Any Error

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony4, webpack-encore

I am trying to add google map search capability for my project and i found a very nice react code for this (https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) but i couldn't add this to symfony 4 based admin panel.

To understand what is wrong i created a new symfony 4 project and just added one controller and a twig template.

Generally i followed the following tutorials
https://www.thinktocode.com/2018/06/21/symfony-4-and-reactjs/ and
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

But when i ran the example i got the following result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome!</title>
            </head>
    <body>
            <div id="root"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/build/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it is just the same code with the index.html.twig; there is no change. React didn't change anything instead of i expected.

This tutorial is not the one i just tried.Also I tried, React Getting Started tutorial and other Symfony 4 + React examples but the result was always same.

You can access the source codes from here:
https://github.com/bahadirarslan/Symfony4ReactProblem

**UPDATE**
I also tried steps described here https://artemzhuravlev.com/blog/symfony-reactjs-using-encore/ but couldn't make it.

The only thing i want to mention, when i try to run `npm install` i always get `EACCES: permission denied` error so i am running `npm install` with `sudo` and `--allow-roo`t attributes like described here https://www.fahidjavid.com/fix-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir/

Comment: Make sure you have added ".addEntry('js/app', ['babel-polyfill', './assets/js/app.js'])" in your webpack config file.

Comment: As you can see in webpack.config.js file it is already added like .addEntry('app', ["@babel/polyfill",'./assets/js/app.js'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution with helps Vincent Le Biannic (https://github.com/Lyrkan) at github.
He took my attention to lines below at `webpack.config.js`

```
// will require an extra script tag for runtime.
// but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

This config make necessary to call `runtime.js` (which was generated by encore) in html file.
But adding only `runtime.js` didn't help so i also added `vendors-app.js` and voila!

Interestingly neither symfony's original documentation nor any tutorial about this subject don't contain any single line about this situation.

Comment: I don’t think Symfony’s documentation role is to teach anyone how to correctly use Webpack and its artifacts. The `enableSingleRuntimeChunk` is described well enough though.

Answer (score -1):

If you see an **EACCES error** when you try to install a package globally, you can either:

- Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended),

or

- Manually change npm’s default directory

**Source** : https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: I tried these instructions but couldn't help me. So i am using with sudo and allow-root attributes and can run the npm install without any error.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem for me
I added the line the twig header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/vendor/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and it works